# log in Screen in eclipse

Tags: database, eclipse, methods, get, set

Good morning.I have a question related to the code of designing the login screen .login screen contains username & password that already saved in the database.I want to first check if it's in the database. I write the code in this way :

```
try {
 String query = "select USERNAME,PASSWORD from USERS"
 pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
 pst.setString(1, txtUsername.getText()); // name of username in design 
 pst.setString(2, txtPassword.getText()); // name of password in design   
 rs = pst.executeQuery();

 if (rs.next()) {

  String name = rs.getString("USERNAME");
  String pass = rs.getString("PASSWORD");
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username&Password Correct");
 } else {

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid login");
 }

 pst.close();
 rs.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

no syntax error but logically something is the wrong .My question is should I use both set/get methods or one of them and where?
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The query should be :

```
SELECT username FROM USERS WHERE username=? AND password=?
```

Set the string values and execute the query, if it returns a value, login success, otherwise fail.

Comment: thank you the return value is correct but i have another question .the other screen depend on the privilege of the user (a coloum in users table) but in login screen there is no txtfield for privilege . i will use if statment but how i can access privilege colum from the code ?

Comment: Modify the query as follows:
SELECT username, privilege FROM USERS WHERE username=? AND password=?

Catch these values in the if block and store it in session if you want to access it on other pages as well

Comment: so the query will be like String query = "select USERNAME,PASSWORD,PRIVILEGE from USERS where USERNAME =? AND PASSWORD =?"; and the value for privilege can i access it lik this ? String pre = rs.getString("PRIVIEGE"); or it's wrong ?

Comment: It's right, except you don't need need the password in the front end. So let the query be :
String query = "select USERNAME,PRIVILEGE from USERS where USERNAME =? AND PASSWORD =?";

Comment: String pre = rs.getString("PRIVIEGE"); >>> this statment gave me invalid column name .maybe i place it in wrong place . if it's correct where should i place it  in the code ?

Comment: if (rs.next()) {

  String name = rs.getString("USERNAME");
  String pre= rs.getString("PRIVILEGE");
 }

Also, check the spelling of the column names.

Comment: Please accept and vote up my answer if it helped you :)